# Probability of a fair coin's $j$th and $k$th rolls have the same outcome

Tags: probability, statistics

A fair die rolls $n$ times, let $R_{j,k}$ be the event that the $j$th and $k$th rolls have the same outcomes. Calculate $P(R_{j,k})$ with $1\leq j,k\leq n$.

Event $R_{j,k}$ has two same outcomes for sure, then the remain $n-2$ rolls can be any number from $1$ to $6$, so $P(R_{j,k})=6\times6^{n-2}/6^n=1/6$.

EDIT:

How to show $R_{j,k}$ are pair-wise independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $j,k$ when $1\leq j<k\leq n$, then $\mathsf P(R_{j,k})=1/6$ as you ascertained.

(Note that when $j=k$, of course $\mathsf P(R_{j,j})=1$ )

To prove distinct events $R_{j,k}$ and $R_{i,h}$ are always pairwise independent, we have to show $\mathsf P(R_{j,k}, R_{i,h})=\mathsf P(R_{j,k})~\mathsf P(R_{i,h})$ for all indices $1\leq j<k\leq n$, $1\leq i<h\leq n$ in the following cases:

- all indices are distinct
- two indices match, the others are distinct

Comment: They are not mutually independent, correct? And I am a little bit confused to read $P(R_{j,k},R_{i,h})$.

Comment: $P(R_{j,k}, R_{i,h})$ is: the probability that die $j$ shows the same result as die $k$, and that die $i$ shows the same as die $h$.  If all indices are distinct, that is clearly $(6/6)(1/6)(6/6)(1/6)$, where as if two of the indices are the same , $(6/6)(1/6)(1/6)$.

Comment: They are not mutually independent because $P (B_{i,j,k,h})=1/6^3$

Comment: @struggle You are not interested in the event that all four coins have the same outcome.  You just want the event that two pairs have the same outcome but not necessarily the same as each other.  [ TT,HH is okay.]

Comment: Yes, $P (R_{j,k},R_{i,h})\neqP (R_{j,k})P (R_{i,h})$ when all indices are different.